# PHP autocomplete parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters, autocomplete

I don't know if it's a IDE question or if there's a way to do this with PHP configuration or something.

I want to know if it's possible to create a autocomplete/intellisense feature for a parameter. For example:

---

```
function sayALetter($letter){
 echo $letter;
}
```

---

Now when I call this function, I want to have some autocomplete options for the $letter parameter. (a, b, c, d). In other words, I want to control which values this parameter can receive.

It's possible or I'm talking crazy?

Comment: You can create an array of acceptable letters and return false when not in array

Comment: basically, yeah, ... you're talking crazy.... ;)

Comment: That's what I though. Crazy.
@Jack. Yeah, I can do that, but that isn't nearly cool as a autocomplete would be. :)

Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but there is a way (sort of). The thing you need is an IDE that can give hints (eg. PhpStorm). It does not prevent passing on different values tho:

```
function letters($letters = "ab"|"ad"|"bf"|"ah"|"bj"|"al"|"cn"|"oc") {
    return $letters;
}
```

[image: Autocomplete php function parameters]

Answer (score 0):

There are IDEs that give you hints as to what parameters a function expects. This is done via a special comment format just before the function.

Even when writing your own functions, if you stick to the format, the documentation of a function's parameters is done in seconds, and it will instantly be visible to you when you type in the name of the function in another part of the code.

They also have autocomplete, filling in the function's parameter variable names from the definition of your function.

If you type in `/**` on a line and hit return on a line just before your function definition, your IDE should fill in the skeleton for your function documentation (parameters and return types).

```
 /**
 * This function bars foos
 * it returns an array in some cases 
 * otherwise it returns FALSE.
 * @param   string   foo being barred
 * @return  mixed   array of barred foos or FALSE
 */
public function foobar($foo)
{....
```

This is very useful, since your IDE can now give you hints inside the function regarding the parameters, i.e. what methods/properties are available for the parameter.

However, since php doesn't really have types, you'll still need to make sure that you're getting what you're expecting inside your function.
This is just your IDE helping you out, PHP itself doesn't care.

Comment: Really interesting. I didn't know that. I presume Netbeans has this "power", am I right? EDIT: I just tried it. It helps. Thanks man!